# Visual C++ seems to be zero-initializing POD members of a class which it shouldn't

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a class like this:

```cpp
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass() {};
    //Note: I wish not to initialize rawMemory (for whatever reason)
    int rawMemory[32];
};

int main()
{
    TestClass obj;
    return 0;
}
```

And after I created a `TestClass` object using `TestClass obj;` I got the behavior I wanted: rawMemory did not get initialized (filled with 0xcc in debug mode and with random undetermined value in release mode).
How ever when I added a pointer member to the class:

```cpp
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass() {};
    int rawMemory[32];
    int* ptr;
};
```

The `rawMemory` got initialized to zero! I think according to the standard this should not happen. I even tried with `std::aligned_storage` which is dedicated for reserving uninitialized automatic memory, and `rawMemory` still got zero-initialized!

```cpp
class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass() {};
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(int), alignof(int)>::type rawMemory[32];
    int* ptr;
};
```

**Note: I have tried g++, it worked as I expected.**
**Update: If I change TestClass into a struct, the problem is gone; If I give `TestClass` a default implicit constructor the problem is gone.**

Comment: The compiler implementation is allowed to do that or not. There's nothing stated in the standard that forbids to do so. Also it might be pure chance that the allocated memory for `rawMemory` already contains zeroes.

Comment: Could be your OS. Your OS may give your process pages that are 0 initialized for security purposes (so that information does not leak from a previous usage of the same ram from some other process)

Comment: The standard doesn't require that the members are initialised.     That is not the same as requiring that they are initialised to something other than zero.

Comment: @drescherjm but vc debugger fills the stack memory with 0xcc before the program runs. How can this happen?

Comment: There is a debug CRT that does the memory fills in debug mode. The release CRT does not.

Comment: @Peter So it is "doesn't require" not "require not to", right? How do I force it not to initialize the memory?

Comment: ***Note: I have tried g++, it worked as I expected.*** Maybe with g++ you are seeing pages that were already used in your own process.

Comment: @FawkesFlammer Why would you assume that memory filled with zeroes (or with any other value) has been initialized?

Comment: @FawkesFlammer -   You can't.   An implementation is permitted to do what it likes, since the standard doesn't impose any constraints.   The point of the wording in the standard is that you can't rely on any particular behaviour occurring - or being prevented.    If uninitialised memory happens to get zero values, them's the breaks.   If uninitialised memory happens to get a value of `42` in every byte, them's also the breaks.  You can't rely on any particular observable behaviour occurring.

Comment: @VTT Because the debugger have filled with 0xcc, and if it was changed to zero, this means something had been done (might be initialization, but I am not very sure)

Comment: Just because the contents of memory happen to be zero doesn't mean the compiler actually generated code to initialize the memory to zero…Zero is one of the most abundant elements commonly found in memory…

Comment: But in any case: Which version of Visual C++ are you using and which compiler flags are you compiling with? You do realize that any modern OS will only ever hand your process zeroed-out memory pages for security reasons?

Comment: The code's behaviour does not depend on the alleged values

Comment: Apart from that: I fail to be able to reproduce the alleged behavior on my machine here. How do you actually check the contents of your memory in your release build? You cannot possibly be doing that using the code from your example above, because `obj` will be optimized away completely…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel /JMC /permissive- /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\ConcurrentQueue.pch" /diagnostics:classic for debug. I have disabled optimization.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel For release it was: /permissive- /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"Release\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /Oi /MD /FC /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\ConcurrentQueue.pch" /diagnostics:classic

Comment: @MichaelKenzel And my Platform Toolset was "Visual Studio 2019 (v142)"

Comment: Ok, and how do you check the contents of the memory? If you look at the assembly that VS 2019 will generate for your example above, you will see that it at no point allocates memory for `obj` because `obj` is completely optimized away (as it should)…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel I have used both std::cout and the quick watch (yes I can use watch in release mode, and it shows objects that are not optimized away)

Comment: Note that your release build is not optimized (`/Od`) if I'm not mistaken. I still cannot reproduce the "problem" here with an optimized build on VS 2019, but also not with a non-optimized build…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192106/discussion-between-fawkes-flammer-and-michael-kenzel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally found the source of this issue.
When a pointer member is present in the class, Visual C++ inserts a `autoclassinit` method call before calling the constructor I defined. This method call somewhat messed up with member initialization, and **it did zero-initialized my `rawMemory` member**.
This behavior can be removed by disabling `/sdl` in the Visual C++ compiler options. However, if it is not very performance-critical (or the bottleneck), my suggestion is to leave it as it is.
Thanks to everyone who tried to help!